# is there any automated refactoring tool that produces a unique android application?

Tags: android, refactoring, automated-refactoring

I have a project template , when i want to produce a unique application manually to update it to the market. I will follow these steps :

1. Right click in the package name
2. Refactor, then Rename
3. Renaming the package in minifest then update the version code
4. finally to clean the code from imports errors such as *.R; errors

My question is there any tool that automate this refactoring process without being involved on it ?
i tried to create a java tool but it consumes memory and some things i have to finalize it manually , i'm searching for this since 3 days and nothings gives you a clear answer.

Comment: do you face any problem in manually doing this? step 4 should not occur

Comment: no i have no problem using it manually , i have created many applications this way , but as im automating the whole process such as creating the application APK ,signing it and also adding photos and text and all works fine , but still i need to automate this so the user will have a clean APK that ready to be updated to the market without any conflict with another applications

Answer (score 1):

> My question is there any tool that automate this refactoring process without being involved on it ?

The new Gradle-based build system can handle this scenario. In fact, it allows you to separate the package name used by `R.java` (to keep it consistent) and the package name used for determining whether the app is unique on the device and in the Play Store.

I recommend that you watch ["The New Android SDK Build System" video from the Google I|O 2013 conference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LCJAgPkpmR0&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIJOOTFfYzhR2d-rcSbBbEE_&index=26) to learn more about what it can do, as Xav definitely covers this scenario.

Note that while it is not a "right click", it should make scripting a solution fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I've solved this problem by converting the template project into JAR and let another small project handle every thing , I've created a small method that updates the minifest in that small project  and i had to update package,ver name and ver code ONLY ,then I've generated the APK using ANT ,however i tested the project and it works fine , hope this will help another people